# Can ElementRef property be set to a javascript interop return value in Blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I am tinkering with CodeMirror on a textarea element. I am using javascript interop to accomplish this and it works fine when applying the code mirror.
However my intention is to return that codemirror element and store that in another elementref.

```
Blazor.registerFunction('BlazorExt.CodeMirrorSetupExt', (element) =>
{
    return CodeMirror.fromTextArea(element,
    {
        mode: 'application/ld+json',
        matchBrackets: true,
        autoCloseBrackets: true,
        indentWithTabs: true,
        lineNumbers: true,
        autofocus: true,
        styleActiveLine: true,
        readOnly: false,
        autoCloseBrackets: true,
        foldGutter: true,
        height: 'auto',
        width: 'auto',
        gutters: ['CodeMirror-linenumbers', 'CodeMirror-foldgutter']
    });
});

        public static ElementRef CodeMirrorSetupExt(this ElementRef elementRef)
    {
        var result = RegisteredFunction.Invoke<ElementRef>("BlazorExt.CodeMirrorSetupExt", elementRef);
        return result;
    }
```

In my component:

```
//in my html i have a textarea with ref of TextArea

ElementRef CodeMirror;
ElementRef TextArea;

protected override void OnAfterRender()
{

    CodeMirror = TextArea.CodeMirrorSetupExt();
}
```

Ideally after this point I should be able to update my codemirror ref using its functions like so.

```
    Blazor.registerFunction('BlazorExt.CodeMirrorUpdateExt', (element, Value) =>
{
    element.getDoc().setValue(Value);
});

        public static void CodeMirrorUpdateExt(this ElementRef elementRef, string Value)
    {
        var args = new object[] { elementRef, Value };
        RegisteredFunction.Invoke<object>("BlazorExt.CodeMirrorUpdateExt", args);
    }
```

In the component again I should be able to update the codemirror like so:

```
CodeMirror.CodeMirrorUpdateExt("somedata");
```

However I get an exception: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Browser.Interop.JavaScriptException: Cannot read property 'getDoc' of null

Is what I am trying to accomplish outside of what is possible or is passing a codemirror javascript object into an elementref not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not (yet) possible. [See here](https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/758)

What you can do, is register your javascript object globally and use that reference for eventual second uses. Like so:

```
Blazor.registerFunction('BlazorExt.CodeMirrorSetupExt', (element) =>
{
  window.mybject = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(element,
  {
     mode: 'application/ld+json',
     matchBrackets: true,
     autoCloseBrackets: true,
     indentWithTabs: true,
     lineNumbers: true,
     autofocus: true,
     styleActiveLine: true,
     readOnly: false,
     autoCloseBrackets: true,
     foldGutter: true,
     height: 'auto',
     width: 'auto',
     gutters: ['CodeMirror-linenumbers', 'CodeMirror-foldgutter']
   });
   return true;
 });

public static void CodeMirrorSetupExt(this ElementRef elementRef)
{
    RegisteredFunction.Invoke<bool>("BlazorExt.CodeMirrorSetupExt", elementRef);
}
```

And then:

```
  Blazor.registerFunction('BlazorExt.CodeMirrorUpdateExt', (element, Value)=>{
    window.myObject.getDoc().setValue(Value);
});
```

Of course you can make this nicer with an array and a key as reference.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you elaborate on how to make it nice using an array and key?

Comment: Well, this quick and dirty solution only allows for one object, which is not ideal. You should make window.myObject an array, and push objects with a random key or something on it, while returning the key to C#. The second interop method should find it again in the array by that key. Or just wait ;-) Steve promised to come up with something build-in in the platform

Answer (score 1):

I extended @Flores answer.  Instead of making a global array of all your javascript objects, just stash the new value inside a javascript DOM object you already have an elementReference to.

```
window.hintCodeMirrorIntegration = {
    initialize: function(element, markupMode) {
        element.codeMirrorLink = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(element,
           {
            ...
            });
        return 0;
    },

    getCode: function(element) {
        return element.codeMirrorLink.getValue();
    }

}
```

On the c# side I pass in the ElementReference to the text area.  I hang on to that reference, and when I want the code ouf of the CodeMirror object, I find it inside the TextArea that I already have a reference to.  This also nicely ties the lifetime of the  CodeMirror object to the text area it is shadowing.

```
 private ElementReference textToEdit;
 protected override Task OnAfterRenderAsync()
  {
      return javascriptRuntime.InvokeAsync<int>("hintCodeMirrorIntegration.initialize", textToEdit,
          Context.CurrentAsset.MimeType);
  }

private async Task Save()
{
    var code = await javascriptRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("hintCodeMirrorIntegration.getCode", textToEdit);
    //... save the result in the database
}
```